# Vuetify/Typescript: Is it possible to see the definition of component attributes?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

E.g. in a v-data-table, the headers object has a specified object in the API:
[image]

Is it possible to get this headers type in Typescript for reuse? Or would i need to create my own interface for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import the type with `import { DataTableHeader } from 'vuetify'`.

You can look into `node_modules/vuetify/types/index.d.ts` to see all exported types.